# Python Socket and Thread pooling, how to get more performance?

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, threadpool, http-get

I am trying to implement a basic lib to issue **HTTP GET** requests. My target is to receive data through **socket connections** - minimalistic design to improve **performance** - usage with **threads, thread pool(s)**.

I have a bunch of links which I group by their hostnames, so here's a simple demonstration of input URLs:

```
hostname1.com - 500 links
hostname2.org - 350 links
hostname3.co.uk - 100 links
...
```

I intend to use sockets because of performance issues. I intend to use a number of sockets which keeps connected (if possible and it usually is) and issue HTTP GET requests. The idea came from urllib low performance on continuous requests, then I met urllib3, then I realized it uses httplib and then I decided to try sockets. So here's what I accomplished till now:

[GETSocket class, SocketPool class, ThreadPool and Worker classes](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/asyncore.html)

GETSocket class is a minified, "HTTP GET only" version of Python's httplib.

So, I use these classes like that:

```
sp = Comm.SocketPool(host,size=self.poolsize, timeout=5)
for link in linklist:
    pool.add_task(self.__get_url_by_sp, self.count, sp, link, results)
    self.count += 1
    pool.wait_completion()
    pass
```

`__get_url_by_sp` function is a wrapper which calls `sp.urlopen` and saves the result to `results` list. I am using a pool of 5 threads which has a socket pool of 5 GETSocket classes.

What I wonder is, is there any other possible way that I can improve performance of this system?

I've read about asyncore [here](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/asyncore.html), but I couldn't figure out how to use same socket connection with `class HTTPClient(asyncore.dispatcher)` provided.

Another point, I don't know if I'm using a blocking or a non-blocking socket, which would be better for performance or how to implement which one.

Please be specific about your experiences, *I don't intend to import another library* to do just HTTP GET so I want to code my own tiny library.

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Multiple threads can't really make HTTP GET operations go faster.  You need to use multiple processes.

Comment: I am aware of that, what I mean is requesting and receiving 5 links from the list at the same time makes it faster to retrieve all links in the list. In that sense, bandwidth is the upper limitation to accomplish it faster.

Processes or threads - don't they offer the same in the end?

Comment: "bandwidth is the upper limitation"  True.  But threads all share the  I/O resources of one  OS process.   Multiple OS processes do not share their I/O resources.

Comment: Using multiple processing or threading is my intention, I am especially after how I can improve my socket interaction. But I can use that idea, can you tell me what it will improve, exactly? As I will process retrieved data after I get them all, would shared or not shared I/O resources be a problem?

Comment: I hate to say it, but if you're running into performance problems it's highly unlikely that httplib is the problem, it's an incredibly thin layer on top of the socket library. If you could provide more explanation of where the performance issue it might be possible to solve the root cause rather than branching off to write your own http lib.

Comment: @synthesizerpatel For beginning I hate BadStatusLine exception. It generally follows with RequestSent kind of error if used within concurrent requests. So one needs to reconnect and this kills the idea of using same socket connection. GETSocket class that I posted, is exactly what I need about functionality. It is a minified version of HTTPConnection, but I am in control of the socket so that I can modify things according to needs.

Comment: With all due respect, it sounds like you weren't using httplib correctly. If the pool managed the httplib objects you wouldn't get the RequestSent error - i.e. attempting to reuse the object before the previous request completed or failed. A couple useful links: http://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2003-May/022635.html, http://code.google.com/p/httplib2/. What you want is the keep-alive support - using multiprocessing is a heavy handed solution to this problem, writing your own socket client will be difficult in the long run, proxies, URL redirection, weird http errors.. no fun from scratch.

Comment: @synthesizerpatel It is weird, I never found the first link of yours. It helped a lot, thanks. Btw did you try httplib2 with Python 3? I had faith in httplib2 but it helped me less than pure HTTPConnection, kept raising strange errors. You are absolutely right, it is no fun from scratch :( But I wonder, won't it make application gain performance, to use just what it will perform (HTTP GET) ?

Comment: @synthesizerpatel I also came accross this situation when dealing with sockets: if you take a look at asyncore.dispatcher page in python documentation, you'll see an http client example. if you could add an `\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\n\r\n` and find a good url, you'll see that it prints out the response as `b'...'` and then an empty bytes object `b''`. I wonder if this extra `b''` causes BadStatusLine somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found a well chosen path to solve my problems. I was using Python 3 for my project and my only option was to use pycurl, so this made me have to port my project back to Python 2.7 series.

Using pycurl, I gained:
- Consistent responses to my requests (actually my script has to deal with minimum 10k URLs)
- With the usage of ThreadPool class I am receiving responses as fast as my system can (received data is processed later - so multiprocessing is not much of a possibility here)

I tried httplib2 first, I realized that it is not acting as solid as it acts on Python 2, by switching to pycurl I lost caching support.

Final conclusion: When it comes to HTTP communication, one could need a tool like (py)curl at his disposal. It is a lifesaver, especially when one is dealing with loads of URLs (try sometimes for fun: you will get lots of weird responses from them)

Thanks for the replies, folks.

Comment: this may resolve the issues of the producer-consumer like problem given before. Therefore, I will give it some credibility. Producer-Consumer info is available at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem

Answer (score 3):

Do this.

Use `multiprocessing`.  http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html.

1. Write a worker `Process` which puts all of the URL's into a `Queue`.
2. Write a worker `Process` which gets a URL from a `Queue` and does a GET, saving a file and putting the File information into another Queue.  You'll probably want multiple copies of this `Process`.  You'll have to experiment to find how many is the correct number.
3. Write a worker `Process` which reads file information from a `Queue` and does whatever it is that you're trying do.

Comment: One huge question: Since I want to re-use socket connections, how to share these sockets with subprocesses? From what I understand the `Queue` objects you mention are for getting results back.

Comment: Each worker `Process` manages it's own socket connection.  It can reuse or not reuse as necessary.  Reuse won't do much good, but each worker `Process` can certainly reuse anything that seems to help.

Comment: I am using multiprocessing.Pool (Python 3), but I couldn't figure out how to use Queue. Should I pass the Queue object as a parameter, or should it be global? I keep getting strange errors :(

Comment: It was just OK to hear "pass it as parameter" or "yeah, a global Queue could work". Anyway. Take a look at [this](http://pastebin.com/UMDN8Geg).

Comment: @Kerem Ulutaş: It's a separate question, not a comment on this question.  Answering a separate question (posed in comments) means that other people will not find that separate question or the separate answer.  Please post the separate question as a separate question so that it will get proper answers and can provide proper help help other people.

Comment: this sounds a lot like a producer-consumer pattern. just for reference.